# SharePoint alerts on changes for Followers

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, sharepoint-alerts

I have a request from an end user who updates content on a site page. When that site is updated is there a way to send an alert to all those that are following that there have been changes or updates? I am thinking this would be a solution using Power Automate and having it trigger on change an email to all "followers" ?

Comment: Are you talking about site followers? When do you want to send an alert, when specific page is changed (page content or metadata)?

Comment: I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that there is no need to use Power Automate to achieve this. SharePoint has an OOTB feature, you can add an Alert on the SitePages Library/Document Library/List/files/folder.

Automatically send emails to all "followers" when changes or updates.

Here are steps：
[image]
[image]

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.